# JavaScript: Setter for inner object

Tags: javascript, object, setter

I have a simple object and constructor in Traditional JavaScript as follows:

```
function Test() {
    this.data={};
}
Test.prototype={
    set value(something) {

    },
    get value() {
        return data[property];
    }
};

var test=new Test();
```

Inside the object is another object, initially with no own properties.

I would like to write a Setter for `value` which sets a property on the inner object (`data`).

```
test.value.whatever=23;
```

Is there any way I can do this?

I expect that the Setter function could then finish the job with something like this:

```
    set value() {
        //  how do I get property & value?
        data[property]=value;   
    },
```

Comment: Setting a property of the `test.value` object does not invoke the `.value` setter, no.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could be making `.value` and object with a `.whatever` setter, or use a proxy to catch all accesses, but there probably is a simpler solution to your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @Bergi I am developing a simple array-like object to contain a number of elements, similar to a `NodeList`. I would like to perform some operations on this object using a similar format to performing them on single elements. I can easily implement `elements.innerHTML`, but `elements.style` requires some nesting. I know that I can use `elements.style(property[,value])`, but I would prefer to mirror the single element operation. I do have an alternative solution, but I would like to learn more about using Getters & Setters.

Comment: @Bergi I am unfamiliar with Proxies, but it looks like a possible solution. I will need to read more on that …

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the tip on Proxies — I have implemented a solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function Test() {
    this.data = {};
}
Test.prototype={
    set value(v) {
        this.data.whatever = v;
    },
    get value() {
        return this.data.whatever;
    }
};
var test = new Test();
test.value = 'hi';
console.log(test.value) // 'hi'
console.log(test.data) // {whatever: 'hi'}
```

Remember to put the `data` property in the constructor. Otherwise, if you put it into the prototype, it will be a shared property among every instance.

Comment: No, I wanted to to know how to set a, _arbitrary_ property of an object _inside_ the object. That’s the `data` object.

Comment: You won't get the desired behavior using the current support of setters & getters. You need to know beforehand all the properties you want to modify. So, if you have a `style` object and you want to give access to every property in it from the parent object, then you will need to write the getter and setter for each one of the properties in the `style` object.

Comment: So... your best option in this case would be something like creating a generic `setStyle(prop, value)` method or go with a `Proxy` construction

Comment: I have implemented a Proxy based solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have an answer: as suggested by @Bergi & @damianmr, I used (and had to learn about) a `Proxy` object.

Here is a working version:

```
function Test() {
    this.dataStore={};
    this.data=new Proxy(this,{
        set(target,property,value) {
            target.dataStore[property]=value;
        },
        get(target,property) {
            return target.dataStore[property];
        }
    });
}
Test.prototype={

};

var test=new Test();
test.data.whatever=23;
test.data.etc=46;

alert(`${test.data.whatever} ${test.data.etc}`);
```

As you can see:

- I have an object called `dataStore`, and a proxy called `data`
- The Proxy is set in the constructor

This is a simple abstracted case, but it also works for the more complex project I’m working on.

The only shortcoming is that IE doesn’t support Proxy, and the polyfills I have seen don’t like new properties.

That just means I will need to supply a functional alternative for Legacy Browsers, and wait for them to die out …

Comment: Of course, in this simple example the proxy doesn't do anything that `this.data = this.dataStore` wouldn't have done as well :-)